# how to create particle disappearing effect in android?

Tags: java, android, animation

The question is to develop a beautiful particle scattering effect on Android for random image. I searched the Internet for quite a long time, but never found anything on this topic. I would be grateful for a code example.

As I said, I tried to find the answer to the question on the Internet, but to no avail. I also tried to program something myself, but that also did not bring results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.